# Handlebar.templates is undefined

Tags: javascript, gulp, handlebars.js, templating

I am trying to pre compile my handlebar template `Home.hbs` but it gives me an error saying cannot read property 'template name' of undefined.

Here is the index file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<link>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
<link href="dist/styles/libs/bootstrap.css"/>
<link href="dist/styles/app.css"/>

</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <h1>This is the home page</h1>

</div>
</body>
<script src="dist/js/thirdparty.js"></script>
<script src="dist/js/templates.js"></script>
<script src="dist/js/main.js"></script>

</html>
```

I am using a gulp-handlebar task to pre-compile it

```
var config ={
   handlebar: {
            path: 'app/templates/pages/**/*.hbs',
            dist: 'dist/js',
            partials: 'app/templates/partials/**/*.hbs'
   }
}
gulp.task('handlebar', function(){
    gulp.src(config.handlebar.path)
        .pipe(handlebars())
        .pipe(wrap('Handlebars.template(<%= contents %>)'))
        .pipe(declare({
            namespace: 'RRI.templates',
            noRedeclare: true, // Avoid duplicate declarations
        }))
        .pipe(concat('templates.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.handlebar.dist));
});
```

Home.hbs

```
<div class="entry">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <div class="body">
        {{body}}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <h2>Hello World!! </h2>
    {{> _search}}
</div>
```

_search.hbs

```
 <h1>search</h1>
```

main.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var template = Handlebars.templates.RRI.templates.Home;
    var context = {title: "My New Post", body: "This is my first post!"};
    var html    = template(context);
    $(".wrapper").append(html);
});
```

It gives me an error on the second line in main.js saying cannot read property RRI of undefined.

template.js file

```
this["RRI"] = this["RRI"] || {};
this["RRI"]["templates"] = this["RRI"]["templates"] || {};
this["RRI"]["templates"]["Home"] = Handlebars.template({"compiler":[6,">= 2.0.0-beta.1"],"main":function(depth0,helpers,partials,data) {
    var stack1, helper, alias1=helpers.helperMissing, alias2="function", alias3=this.escapeExpression;

  return "\r\n\r\n<div class=\"entry\">\r\n    <h1>"
    + alias3(((helper = (helper = helpers.title || (depth0 != null ? depth0.title : depth0)) != null ? helper : alias1),(typeof helper === alias2 ? helper.call(depth0,{"name":"title","hash":{},"data":data}) : helper)))
    + "</h1>\r\n    <div class=\"body\">\r\n        "
    + alias3(((helper = (helper = helpers.body || (depth0 != null ? depth0.body : depth0)) != null ? helper : alias1),(typeof helper === alias2 ? helper.call(depth0,{"name":"body","hash":{},"data":data}) : helper)))
    + "\r\n    </div>\r\n</div>\r\n\r\n<div class=\"wrapper\">\r\n    <h2>Hello World!! </h2>\r\n"
    + ((stack1 = this.invokePartial(partials._search,depth0,{"name":"_search","data":data,"indent":"    ","helpers":helpers,"partials":partials})) != null ? stack1 : "")
    + "</div>\r\n";
},"usePartial":true,"useData":true});
```

I am using Handlebar 3.0.1 , please help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally this is what worked for me , minor change in template.js

```
 var template = RRI.templates.Home;
```

I found this after some debugging but this definitely means that either I have done something weird or either the Handlebar Docs are not updated.